# Evoking and detaching bash scripts from current shell

Tags: bash

I'm have a tad bit of difficulty with developing bash based deployment scripts for a pipeline I want to run on an OpenStack VM. There are 4 scripts in total:

1. head_node.sh - launches the vm and attaches appropriate disk storage to the VM. Once that's completed, it runs the scripts (2 and 3) sequentially by passing a command through ssh to the VM.
2. install.sh - VM-side, installs all of the appropriate software needed by the pipeline.
3. run.sh - VM-side, mounts storage on the VM and downloads raw data from object storage. It then runs the final script, but does so by detaching the process from the shell created by ssh using `nohup ./pipeline.sh &`. The reason I want to detach from the shell is that the next portion is largely just compute and may take days to finish. Therefore, the user shouldn't have to keep the shell open that long and it should just run in the background.
4. pipeline.sh - VM-side, essentially a for loop that iterates through a list of files, and sequential runs commands on those and intermediate files. The result are analysed which are then staged back to the object storage. The VM then essentially tells the head node to kill it.

Now I'm running into a problem with nohup. If I launch the pipeline.sh script normally (i.e. without nohup) and keep it attached to that shell, everything runs smoothly. However, if I detach the script, it errors out after the first command in the first iteration of the for loop. Am I thinking about this the wrong way? What's the correct way to do this?

So this is how it looks:

$./head_node.sh

head_node.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
... launched VM etc
ssh $vm_ip './install.sh'
ssh $vm_ip './run.sh'
exit 0
```

install.sh - omitted - not important for the problem

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
... mounts storage downloads appropriate files
nohup ./pipeline.sh > log &
exit 0
```

pipeline.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $(find . -name '*ext')
do 
process1 $f
process2 $f
...
done
... stage files to object storage, unmount disks, additional cleanups
ssh $head_node 'nova delete $vm_hash'
exit 0
```

Comment: Try `disown` first. I always prefer shell builtins to external commands that try to stretch their limits to do what really should be done with builtins.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, 4ae1e1. ill try that and see what happens.\

Comment: As a side note: 1. Don't forget to double-quote every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: "$var", "$(command "$var")" etc. 2. Regarding *pipline.sh*: The first *for* loop is dangerous, please take a look [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1). I suggest you to replace it with `while read -rd $'\0' f;do ...;done < <(find . -name '*ext' -print0)`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Rany. Yea, I had run into this problem with literals earlier. Luckily the filepaths are well formed, so I don't have to worry about whitespace (except between filepaths) or blob inputs, but still what your suggesting makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm evoking the run.sh script from an ssh instance, subprocesses launched from the script (namely pipeline.sh) will not properly detach from the shell and will error out on termination of the ssh instance evoking run.sh. The pipeline.sh script can be properly detached by calling it from the head node, e.g., nohup ssh $vm_ip './pipeline.sh' &, this will keep the session alive until the end of the pipeline.